# Block-like environment in beamer (using tikz's current page coordinates)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, coordinates, tikzmark, current-page

I am trying to define an environment that looks like the following (see picture and code below)

- the environment body is  contained in a background rectangle;
- this rectangle extends to the edges of the slide; and
- the block title on above top-right corner of the rectangle).

[image: Example block (shaded)]

I would like to automate the choice of tikzmark names, so that I could have multiple environments per slide.

I could define a throwaway counter (say `myblctr`) and prefix (say, `mymark-` so that every new occurence of the environment would use `mymark-AA-\themyblctr`…

Is there a better way?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{asdxb}

  Example slide\ldots

  \bigskip
  \bigskip

  % Draw box
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (left)  at ($(pic cs:AA) +(0,\baselineskip)$);
    \coordinate (right) at ($(pic cs:BB) +(0,\baselineskip)$); 
    \fill[yellow!50!gray!35!white] ($(left-|current page.west)$) rectangle ($(right-|current page.east)$);

    % Block title
    \node [anchor=base east] at (left-|current page.east) {Mathew (Mat) Sean};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  %
  % Contents of block
  \tikzmark{AA}Text inside of the block\newline
  Should work for multiple lines
  \[ \text{with} + \text{equations} \sqrt{\text{inside}} \]%
  \tikzmark{BB}
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{sharp corners,oversize,attach boxed title to top right={xshift=-0.7cm},enhanced,coltitle=black,left=1cm,right=1cm, boxrule=0mm,titlerule=0mm,boxed title style={empty}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title={blub}]
test
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know this package!